# Test-Path -Path showing as empty string

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use `Test-Path` in the registry, sample code:

```
$RegistryLocation = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
```

This works fine:

```
Test-Path -Path $RegistryLocation
```

True. Now without the final asterisk character:

```
$NewRegistryLocation = $RegistryLocation.Split("*")
Test-Path -Path $NewRegistryLocation
```

`Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.`

But this works (value of `$NewRegistryLocation` variable):

```
Test-Path -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Wouldn't `split("*")` create an array with the second value being null (part after * in the original string)? Null would result in error.

Comment: `$NewRegistryLocation` is not a string but a string array. You can view it's type by `$NewRegistryLocation.GetType()`. Use`$NewRegistryLocation[0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Split()` method breaks the string in two every time it finds the character(s) you give it, producing an array.  It isn't just removing the character from the end of the string.

There are a number of ways to get around this in your case:

1. If possible, don't add the asterisk to the string in the first place
2. Use only the first item in the array: `$NewRegistryLocation = $RegistryLocation.Split("*")[0]`
3. Use `Split-Path` (which does what I think you intended): `$NewRegistryLocation = Split-Path -Path $RegistryLocation -Parent`
4. use the `-replace` operator to remove the asterisk: `$NewRegistryLocation =  $RegistryLocation -replace "\*",""`

Method 3 is probably what I'd recommend as it's a bit more robust and 'PowerShelly'.

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace this line

```
$NewRegistryLocation = $RegistryLocation.Split("*")
```

with this

```
$NewRegistryLocation = $RegistryLocation.Split("*")[0]
```

so your `NewRegistryLocation` will still contain a string and not an array.